# Check if a downstream job is enabled before triggering it

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job (JobA) which, upon success, builds JobB. The Jenkinsfile for JobA contains a post section like this:

```
post {
  success {
    build job: 'JobB', wait: false
  }
}
```

The problem is that when `JobB` is disabled, JobA will fail no matter what with the following message:

```
ERROR: Failed to trigger build of JobB
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can I prevent JobA from failing when JobB is disabled while still using declarative syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Before triggering the post job, you can first check if JobB is enabled/disabled via isBuildable().

```
Jenkins.instance.getItem("JobB").isBuildable()
```

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this w/o executing a custom script? i.e. an option to `build job: xxx`?

Comment: The only other solution I can think of is using a try/catch/finally inside success{}.

Comment: note: this requires (1) the groovy sandbox to be disabled and (2) script approval.